# jQuery smooth scroll jumps in the end

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I've created a smooth scroll navigation on a one pager. This seems to work, but and the end of the scroll, my page "jumps" weirdly.

http://ontop.houston-1.hybridmedia.be/

My jQuery code is pretty simple and straightforward:

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('a[href*="#"]').on('click', function (el) {
        el.preventDefault();

        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 500, 'linear');
    });
});
```

In HTML:

```
<a href="#story">story</a>

<section id="story">
</section>
```

What is happening over here? I've already tried some other scripts, but the have to same issue.

Comment: It seems to be connected with the `hashchange` event, e.g. if you click on Contact, wait for the URL to change to `#contact`, scroll a bit and then click Contact _again_, it will not jump. My guess is that you have a hashchange event that clashes with your scrolling

Comment: Active code looked like [this](https://pastebin.com/hXB8Fp0W). The callback caused the jump, script in the question should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it without the hashtag and by adding a data attribute to the link element

```
<a data-tag="story" class="primary-nav__list__item__link scroll">story</a>

<section id="story"></section>
```

My jQuery code:

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('a.scroll').on('click', function (el) {
        el.preventDefault();

        href = $(this).data('tag');

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#'+ href).offset().top - 150
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Now your HTML Code is invalid. An a-tag needs a href attribute.

Comment: FYI you didn't really fix the issue, you're now just bypassing it. Without `href="#"`, the hash is not updated, hence the `hashchange` event is not fired, that's why now it works.